# Adding gradient to moving objects in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, gradient, trigonometry

I want to add gradient to the ball in this program & also possibly the waves drawn to fade into the colour of the background (as if glowing) instead of one colour fills.

I've looked at tons of tutorials however none of them are making much sense to my syntax, the general idea to me is confusing as I have moving objects that draw the space I want to add gradient to quite slowly. Can anyone give an insight into how I can do this?

code:

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *

# set up of constants
WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
DARKRED    = (128,   0,   0)
RED        = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK      = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN      = (  0, 255,   0) 
BLUE       = (  0,   0, 255) 

BGCOLOR = WHITE

screen = pygame.display.set_mode()
WINDOWWIDTH = 800 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 800 # height in pixels
WIN_CENTERX = int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) # the midpoint for the width of the window
WIN_CENTERY = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) # the midpoint for the height of the window

screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

FPS = 160 # frames per second to run at

AMPLITUDE = 80 # how many pixels tall the waves with rise/fall.

# standard pygame setup code
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('Window title')
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)

# variables that track visibility modes
showSine = True
showSquare = True 

pause = False

xPos = 0
step = 0 # the current input f


posRecord = {'sin': [], 'square': []} # keeps track of the ball positions for drawing the waves

yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE # starting position

# main application loop
while True:
    # event handling loop for quit events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    # fill the screen to draw from a blank state
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

    # sine wave
    yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE
    posRecord['sin'].append((int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSine:
        # draw the sine ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        sinLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(sinLabelSurf, sinLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSine:
        for x, y in posRecord['sin']:
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, DARKRED, (x,y), 4)

    #drawing horizontal lines
    # square 
    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSquare:
        # draw the sine ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        squareLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(squareLabelSurf, squareLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSquare:
        for x, y in posRecord['square']:
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (x, y), 4)

    # draw the border
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1)

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    if not pause:
        xPos += 1

        #wave movement
        if xPos > WINDOWWIDTH:
            #sine 
            xPos = 0
            posRecord['sin'] = []
            step = 0


            # square 
            yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE
            posRecord['square'] = []
        else:
            #sine 
            step += 0.008
            #step %= 2 * math.pi

            # square 
            # jump top and bottom every 100 pixels
            if xPos % 100 == 0:
                yPosSquare *= -1
                # add vertical line
                for x in range(-AMPLITUDE, AMPLITUDE):
                    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(x) + WIN_CENTERY))
```

Comment: You could create bitmap with ball with gradient in Photoshop, Gimp or even Inkscape (it create vector graphic but you can convert it to bitmap)

Comment: thanks furas, http://pastebin.com/PbuNhg9p there's an interesting use of gradient here in the making of a bar line. Would similar development be possible for the sin wave?

Comment: Wave is created with many circles - you can use Surface with circle and use `set_alpha()` to make it transparent. Every circle can have different transparent - so it could look like fading.

Comment: Possibility of an example?

Comment: +i will continue studying this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SPACE` to change background color.

First line use only transparency - and has no problem with different background color.
Second line changes only circles color - and depends on background color.
Third and fourth line (it is the same line with different starting color) change circles color and transparency - and depends on background color.

Second and last line look good on one color background and need more work to find good-looking fading.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,200))

#--------------------------------------
# circles positions and transparency (x,y, alpha)

circles = []

for x in range(100):
    circles.append( [100+x*3, 200, x*2] )

#--------------------------------------

white = True # background color

#--------------------------------------

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                white = not white

    #--------------------------------------

    if white:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
    else:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

    #--------------------------------------
    # first

    circle_img = pygame.Surface((20,20))
    pygame.draw.circle(circle_img, (255,0,0), (10,10), 10)
    circle_img.set_colorkey(0)

    for x in circles:

        circle_img.set_alpha(x[2])

        screen.blit(circle_img, (x[0],40))

    #--------------------------------------
    # second

    circle_img = pygame.Surface((20,20))

    for x in circles:

        pygame.draw.circle(circle_img, (255,255-x[2],255-x[2]), (10,10), 10)
        circle_img.set_colorkey(0)

        screen.blit(circle_img, (x[0],90))

    #--------------------------------------
    # last

    circle_img = pygame.Surface((20,20))

    for x in circles:

        pygame.draw.circle(circle_img, (255,255-x[2],255-x[2]), (10,10), 10)
        circle_img.set_colorkey(0)
        circle_img.set_alpha(x[2])

        screen.blit(circle_img, (x[0],140))

    #--------------------------------------

    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

[image]

[image]